# HTML2PDF - The content of a TD tag does not fit on only one page

Tags: php, html2pdf

Php produces pdf without issue when  does not span, nested tables are *not* in use, and

```
HTML2PDF::$_subobj->pdf->getPage();
```

doesn't seem to address the bug/issue. Anyone run into this ERROR n°7?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this error?

Answer (score 5):

Add the following in your function to solve the error

```
html2pdf->setTestTdInOnePage(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long picture (in table td) , example 1200px you can get this error.
I fixed my picture to 600px and problem solved.

Example: My photo is 3000x2000 (width:height)
I resized photo to 600x400.